# How to escape the ampersand character while using sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I want to replace all single quotes in a string with two single quotes using sed. But when the string contains the `&` character, the sed command is not replacing single quotes that come after that.  How can I escape the `&` character so that the single quotes after it are still replaced?

Answer (score 33):

You don't need to escape anything **in the input**:

```
$ echo "123 ' foo & b'ar" | sed "s/'/''/g"
123 '' foo & b''ar
```

However, in the 'replacement' part of the `s` command `&` has a special meaning: it means 'match'. That's why the above command can be re-written as:

```
$ echo "123 ' foo & b'ar" | sed "s/'/&&/g"
123 '' foo & b''ar
```

Escape it with a `\` like everything else that needs to be escaped, if needed:

```
$ echo "123 ' foo & b'ar" | sed "s/'/'\&'/g"
123 '&' foo & b'&'ar
```

Answer (score 13):

It's easier to answer if you post your code, but I'm guessing you're not escaping the ampersand.  Change `&` to `\&` if you want a literal ampersand.

See section 3.1.2 of [The sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html) for a more detailed explantion, if you're curious.

Comment: Hey, I want to replace a string with `&` in my output string. I have tried `"&"`, `\&`, `\\&`, `\\\&`, `"'\&'"` based on different answers on web but nothing works, any suggestions?

Comment: `\&` works for me.  For example, I can replace all instances of `amp` with `&` by using `sed "s/amp/\&/g"`.  If you're still having problems, you should post a new question with your input string and your code.

Comment: Yea it does. I was using another file which did not have the change :(

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me

```
bash>echo "'This is a string with 'single quote' & '&'" | sed "s/'/''/g"
''This is a string with ''single quote'' & ''&''
```